# scrapy_splash scraped 0 items

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm new to scrapy, but dealing with a particularly complicated website that involves both a form and java code. I'm trying to scrape news release data from a UN website, but I don't think the website is being rendered properly, because nothing's getting scraped. Below is my scrapy code and the output.

**Scrapy code**

```
import scrapy
import scrapy_splash
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class OhchrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'OHCHR'
    custom_settings = {
        'SPLASH_URL': 'http://localhost:8050',
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
            'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
        },
        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
        },
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url='http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/NewsSearch.aspx',
            callback=self.parse,
        )


    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            '#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_RadDatePickerFromDate_dateInput_text': '1/1/2016',
            '#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_RadDatePickerToDate_dateInput_text': '2/1/2016',
        }
        return scrapy_splash.SplashFormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=data,
            callback=self.parse_table
        )


    def parse_table(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_lblTitle::text').extract(),
            'date': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_lblDate::text').extract(),
            'type': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_NewsType li::text').extract(),
            'country': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_CountryID li::text').extract(),
            'mandate': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_MandateID li::text').extract(),
            'subject': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_SubjectID li::text').extract(),
         }
```

**Output**

```
$ scrapy runspider OHCHR.py
2018-04-25 13:24:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-04-25 13:24:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) - [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Darwin-17.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-04-25 13:24:55 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-04-25 13:24:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-04-25 13:25:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/NewsSearch.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2018-04-25 13:25:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/NewsSearch.aspx via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2018-04-25 13:25:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/NewsSearch.aspx>
{'title': [], 'date': [], 'type': [], 'country': [], 'mandate': [], 'subject': []}
2018-04-25 13:25:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-04-25 13:25:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 124315,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 595937,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 25, 17, 25, 4, 589322),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 66322432,
 'memusage/startup': 66322432,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 2,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 25, 17, 24, 56, 257819)}
2018-04-25 13:25:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your log indicates that everything is fine and scrapy is returning one item:

`2018-04-25 13:25:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/NewsSearch.aspx>
{'title': [], 'date': [], 'type': [], 'country': [], 'mandate': [], 'subject': []}`

However, your xpaths don't seem to find anything on the page.

To debug this you can use `inspect_response` debug function scrapy has:

```
 def parse_table(self, response):
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

Then run the spider and python will open up shell once it reaches `parse_table` method.
There you can inspect response and see what page you are receiving with functions such as:

`view(response)` - will open up page in your browser.
`response.xpath` - you can try out your xpaths.
etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem related to scrapy_splash, I can get the element by the following way:
check the POST request in chrome devtools network, copy the body and use it in FormRequest. You may want to change `fromdate` and `todate` .

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class OhchrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ohchr'
    allowed_domains = ['www.ohchr.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.ohchr.org/EN/NewsEvents/Pages/NewsSearch.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            # copy all the data in the post body to here
            'MSOTlPn_View': '0',
            'MSOTlPn_ShowSettings': 'False',
            # ......
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SearchNewsID$RadDatePickerFromDate$dateInput': '2016-01-01-00-00-00',
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SearchNewsID$RadDatePickerToDate$dateInput': '2016-02-01-00-00-00',
        }
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response, \
                            formdata = data,\
                            callback = self.parse_table)]

    def parse_table(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_lblTitle::text').extract(),
            'date': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_lblDate::text').extract(),
            'type': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_NewsType li::text').extract(),
            'country': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_CountryID li::text').extract(),
            'mandate': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_MandateID li::text').extract(),
            'subject': response.css('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SearchNewsID_gvNewsSearchresult_ctl03_SubjectID li::text').extract(),
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem, if I do this, is _VIEWSTATE. It's really long and I can't seem to specify it /put it in like everything else. Do you know of a workaround?